# Epidemiology cohort studies question

Tags: experiment-design, epidemiology, case-cohort

If we are conducting a cohort study of factors associated with recurrent myocardial infarctions (MI) following the first one, should our study population at baseline include subjects who had previously suffered from one MI, *or* subjects free from any previous MI?

Answer (score 1):

If you are truly interested in risk factors for MI *among* those with one MI, then you should enroll people with one MI already. In this case, you are not interested in people who never have an MI, nor are you interested in people who die at first MI, so enrolling these people would not be the most efficient use of resources.

However, you don't want to just enroll anyone who ever had 1 MI, because then people with only 1 and no more MIs and people who survive longer after their MI will both be over-represented in your sample. You should try to enroll people as close as possible to the time of their first MI - for example upon hospital discharge for 1st MI.